# OneLogin developer account initial login invalid

Tags: onelogin

I created a OneLogin developer account with username and password, but the login page says invalid username or password.  Resetting the password did not help.  Is there a delay between when you setup the developer account/username/password and when it becomes activated/available for use?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a customer service-related question, not a programming question. We cannot provide support or help for your specific account at an off-site vendor or service. Contact that vendor directly for help with your account.

Comment: Their support link redirects to this forum.  It's possible they don't realize it?

Comment: We accept questions related to programming  (code) or use of a programmer's tool (IDE, compiler, etc.). If they direct you here for other types of question, they're doing it incorrectly. All questions here must meet this site's guidelines. See [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) for more information. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.